# Riot.js 2: Attribute with falsy value

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I need to have an attribute which can have value of zero (`0`)

Riot template:

```
<my-tag time="{ time }">

this.time = condition ? '10' : '0'

</my-tag>
```

Desired result:

```
<my-tag time="0"></my-tag>
```

However, Riot automatically omits whole attribute if it has falsy value:

```
<my-tag></my-tag>
```

My current workaround:

```
this.on('updated', () => {
  $(this.root).attr('time', this.time)
})
```

In other words, i need `time` attribute to have exact value of `time` property.

**Edit:**

Looks like this has changed since 2.2.4.

[Demo with Riot 2.2.4](http://jsbin.com/jaziwiroyu/1/edit?html,console)

this works as expected - both tags have rendered attribute `time` with according value

[Demo with Riot 2.3.13](http://jsbin.com/rakubeteli/1/edit?html,console)

this fails - tag with attribute set to `false` has whole attribute removed

Comment: I'm not sure you can put expressions on a custom tag in its definition. Can't you put the expression on some inner node? Also, only boolean attributes (e.g. checked, selected) are removed if the their value is falsy (http://riotjs.com/guide/#expressions).

Comment: @Antoine: yes, you can put expressions in custom tag itself. it works as excepted. putting it on some inner node has same effect.

Comment: that's weird, I cannot reproduce the issue on children nodes (using v2.2.4, not the latest). I'm not using the compiler (similar to gihrig's workflow), so I cannot test on tag itself.

Comment: @Antoine: edited my questions - looks like this works in 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

This is working in riot v2.3.18:

```
<my-tag time="{ time ? '10' : '0'}">
    <script>
    this.time = false;
    </script>
</my-tag>
```

will generate

```
<my-tag time="0"></my-tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your attribute with "riot-"

```
<my-tag riot-time="{ time }">
```

I had a similar problem

```
<div class="fldr" data-stat="{ s }">
```

When s = 0, renders as

```
<div class="fldr">
```

This worked in my case

```
<div class="fldr" riot-data-stat="{ s }">
```

Note that I am not using the riot compiler, I write the Javascript the compiler would produce, you may have to bypass the Riot compiler for this to work. Just look at your compiled my-tag.js and go from there.

Riot API docs on riot.tag() http://riotjs.com/api/#manual-construction